# Loops in multiple threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading, ruby-1.9

I have the following code ([from a Ruby tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_multithreading.htm)):

```
require 'thread'

count1 = count2 = 0
difference = 0
counter = Thread.new do
   loop do
      count1 += 1
      count2 += 1
   end
end
spy = Thread.new do
   loop do
      difference += (count1 - count2).abs
   end
end
sleep 1

puts "count1 :  #{count1}"
puts "count2 :  #{count2}"
puts "difference : #{difference}"
counter.join(2)
spy.join(2)
puts "count1 :  #{count1}"
puts "count2 :  #{count2}"
puts "difference : #{difference}"
```

It's an example for using `Mutex.synchronize`. On my computer, the results are quite different from the tutorial. After calling `join`, the counts are sometimes equal:

```
count1 :  5321211
count2 :  6812638
difference : 0
count1 :  27307724
count2 :  27307724
difference : 0
```

and sometimes not:

```
count1 :  4456390
count2 :  5981589
difference : 0
count1 :  25887977
count2 :  28204117
difference : 0
```

I don't understand how it is possible that the difference is still `0` even though the counts show very different numbers.

The `add` operation probably looks like this:

```
val = fetch_current(count1)
add 1 to val
store val back into count1
```

and something similar for `count2`. Ruby can switch execution between threads, so it might not finish writing to a variable, but when the CPU gets back to the thread, it should continue from the line where it was interrupted, right?

And there is still just one thread that is writing into the variable. How is it possible that, inside the `loop do` block, `count2 += 1` is executed much more times?

Comment: what does `join(2)` supposed to do?

Comment: it gives the thread a limit (in seconds) to terminate. if I won't call this, ruby will reap threads automatically when reaches the end of programme (so infinite `loop do` will always end). see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Thread.html#method-i-join for more info

Comment: That's interesting. On ruby 1.8 the `difference` is always <> 0, and the counts never differ by more than 1, but on ruby 1.9 the `difference` is always == 0 but count1 and count2 are far apart from each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Execution of

```
puts "count1 :  #{count1}"
```

takes some time (although it may be short). It is not done in an instance. Therefore, it is not mysterious that the two consecutive lines:

```
puts "count1 :  #{count1}"
puts "count2 :  #{count2}"
```

are showing different counts. Simply, the `counter` thread went though some loop cycles and incremented the counts while the first `puts` was executed.

Similarly, when

```
difference += (count1 - count2).abs
```

is calculated, the counts may in principle increment while `count1` is referenced before `count2` is referenced. But there is no command executed within that time span, and I guess that the time it takes to refer to `count1` is much shorter than the time it takes for the `counter` thread to go through another loop. Note that the operations done in the former is a proper subset of what is done in the latter. If the difference is significant enough, which means that `counter` thread had not gone through a loop cycle during the argument call for the `-` method, then `count1` and `count2` will appear as the same value.

A prediction will be that, if you put some expensive calculation after referencing `count1` but before referencing `count2`, then `difference` will show up:

```
difference += (count1.tap{some_expensive_calculation} - count2).abs
# => larger `difference`
```

Comment: In fact putting something like `sleep 0.001` in the counter thread between the counters also make the difference show up. Since the counter thread is "busy looping" I wonder if the spy thread even gets much chance to run in 1.9. Putting the sleep statement in immidiately frees CPU time to run the spy thread, and the difference shows up.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. replacing `puts` by `print "count1 :  #{count1}, count2 :  #{count2}\n"` could decrease the difference between counters. Because `puts` is executed as two commands and therefore takes a bit more time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer. I think you've made the assumption that the threads stop execution after `join(2)` returns.

This is not the case! The threads continue to run even though `join(2)` returns execution (temporarily) back to the main thread.

If you change your code to this you will see what happens:

```
...
counter.join(2)
spy.join(2)

counter.kill
spy.kill

puts "count1 :  #{count1}"
puts "count2 :  #{count2}"
puts "difference : #{difference}"
```

This seems to work a bit differently in ruby 1.8, where the threads do not seem to get a chance to run while the main thread is executing.

The tutorial is probably written for ruby 1.8, but the threading model has been changed since then in 1.9.

In fact it was pure "luck" that it worked in 1.8, as the threads do not finish execution when `join(2)` returns in neither 1.8 nor 1.9.